# ion auth and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I am playing with codeigniter and ion auth for the first time. I have got everything working however, in the ion auth template, the index view displays a list of all users.

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user->first_name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->last_name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->email;?></td>
        <td>
            <?php foreach ($user->groups as $group):?>
                <?php echo anchor("auth/edit_group/".$group->id, $group->name) ;?><br />
            <?php endforeach?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo ($user->active) ? anchor("auth/deactivate/".$user->id, 'Active') : anchor("auth/activate/". $user->id, 'Inactive');?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor("auth/edit_user/".$user->id, 'Edit') ;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Normally the $users array would come from the model. however upon looking into the model(ion_auth_model), I cant see anything specific to $users. the auth controller doesn't give me too much either.

in the [documentation](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), the users() function is:
$users = $this->ion_auth->users();

I presume this is the array being populated on the index page. How is this pulling the MySQL data if not in a model? how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Smudger - look a little closer, the ion_auth_model has a function users() starting around line 1125 (depending on your version) that takes an optional $groups argumant

Comment: Thanks jmadsen, I cannot find that function anywhere in the ion_auth_model. version is [link]https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/zipball/2 any ideas or am I being a total idiot?

Comment: I assume the zip file is the same as the git repo:  https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/ion_auth_model.php  line 1150